# How to play a ringtone from the iPhone in my Xamarin.iOS application?

Tags: c#, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ringtone

I can't seem to find anything on internet about it..

I need to trigger a ringtone (which could be chosen by the user later on) on a specific event but for now just playing a ringtone (or music) would be alright.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SDK API to play a ringtone on iOS but you could play a local file. Have you had a look at the Xamarin tutorial [Playing Sound with AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/)

This will let you play local files like so:

```
// Initialize background music
songURL = new NSUrl("Sounds/"+filename);
NSError err;
backgroundMusic = new AVAudioPlayer (songURL, "wav", out err);
backgroundMusic.Volume = MusicVolume;
backgroundMusic.FinishedPlaying += delegate { 
    backgroundMusic = null;
};
backgroundMusic.NumberOfLoops=-1;
backgroundMusic.Play();
backgroundSong=filename;
```

If it is a message sounds (≤30 seconds), not a ringtone, you could try using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`

Here is a list of all the [system sound Ids](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices), also at this [GitHub](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) too. 1007 is the standard Tri-Tone notification sound.

`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1003);`

There is some talk about your app being rejected when using `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` but I can't see any solid proof also here is Apple's sample code to play a [system sound](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SysSound/Introduction/Intro.html)

The iOS SDK does not bundle these sound files, but they are on the device in the `/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/` folder. Ringtone are located here `/Library/Ringtones/` Someone did mention these are copyrighted, so if you are bundling them in your app then beware.

Then play the sound like so:

```
var s = new SystemSound (soundId);
s.PlayAlertSound ();
```

**Beware**

Bundling copyrighted sounds from Apple will probably get your app rejected

Comment: Thank you very much 
var s = new SystemSound (soundId);
s.PlayAlertSound ();
Did the trick ! :) And thanks for the explanations !

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.